# How do I accept socket connections in a simple TCP server running on OS X?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp

I am writing a simple server in the internet domain using TCP. I have working code that creates a socket, binds it to the server's IP address and listens for connections. 
I want to use the accept() system call to accept connections. I have included the headers listed in accept's man page (http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/accept.txt). But my IDE says it doesn't know what accept() is. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "tcp_server.h"

void error(char* msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
} 

tcp_server::tcp_server(int portno)
{
    sockfd_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd_ < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR opening socket on server.");
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr_, sizeof(serv_addr_));

    serv_addr_.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr_.sin_port = htons(portno);
    serv_addr_.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sockfd_, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr_, sizeof(serv_addr_)) < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR on binding socket to server address.");
    }

    listen(sockfd_, 5);

    clilen_ = sizeof(cli_addr_);
    newsockfd_ = accept(sockfd_, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr_, &clilen_);
}
```

I call accept() in the last line posted above. Isn't accept() available under OS X? How do I do this right?

Here is "tcp_server.h":

```
#pragma once 

class tcp_server
{
public:
    tcp_server(int portno);
    ~tcp_server();
    void set_cli_addr(); 

private:
    int sockfd_, newsockfd_, portno_, clilen_, n_;
    char buffer_[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr_, cli_addr_;

};
```

I get the following error when I compile tcp_server.cpp manually:

```
tcp_server.cpp:53:18: error: no matching function for call to 'accept'
newsockfd_ = accept(sockfd_, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr_, &clilen_);
             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:681:5: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int *' to 'socklen_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') for 3rd argument
int     accept(int, struct sockaddr * __restrict, socklen_t * __restrict)
```

Comment: `accept()` is available and you have the right header file included (`<sys/socket.h>`). What error are you getting? Have you tried compiling it from the command line? I tried compiling your code but I don't have your header file `tcp_server.h`.

Comment: Hmm, [`accept`](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/accept.2.html) should be available under _OSX_. Don't you have a variable called `accept`? What is the full error message?

Comment: What does _the compiler_ say?

Comment: I found the problem: The third argument of accept() expects an unsigned int pointer, while I was passing an int pointer. Im surprised that ints cannot by typecast to unsigned ints.

Comment: @ForceBru I added the compiler error message to my question above.

Comment: @wutschkef You need to declare clilen_ to be of type socklen_t, not int.

Comment: Your IDE didn't say anything of the sort. 'candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int *' to 'socklen_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') for 3rd argument' is not the same thing as 'it doesn't know what accept() is'. You need to read error messages more carefully. They do contain information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a C++ compiler to compile C code.  The two languages are not the same, despite the common roots.

The C++ error message tells you what is going on -- C++ is much more strict about types of arguments to a function (particularly pointer types) as it uses them for overloading.  In C on the other hand, function arguments are not so strict and a pointer is a pointer, giving you at most a warning if you use the wrong pointer type.